# Each is correct

Tags: adverbials

Today I was talking with my boyfriend and I said:

> I wanted to know if you got safe at work

and he answered me like that

> Oh sorry, I got **there** safe.

But I automatically said it’s wrong to use "there", but he claims it’s correct, but English is my first language and English is his first language, but I felt it was wrong because I have learned different. Would someone explain to me so I can show him please.

Comment: "There" is correct in standard English. In this context, it means "to [that place]", so he said, "I got to work safe." The confusion may be because of your variety of English. "I wanted to know if you got safe at work" is not correct English in any variety that I'm familiar with.

Comment: The original statement should have been "I wanted to know if you got to work safely".

Comment: Your boyfriend was correct. You can use 'there' to refer back to a previously mentioned place. Did you get to your mother's house before it started to rain? Yes, I got **there** without getting wet. Have you been to France? Yes, I went **there** last year.

Comment: I suggest perhaps OP's boyfriend is a "keeper". Strictly speaking, using ***here*** rather than ***there*** in the cited context isn't "correct" if he's at work at time of utterance, but the usage certainly does occur. And to my mind, the most *likely* reason for using ***there*** is the speaker is so emotionally involved in his co-conversant, he's just automatically switching to reflect the geographical location from ***her*** perspective. *What a guy! What a [lucky] doll!*

Comment: Of course, even ignoring that somewhat contrived "From whose point of view?" perspective, there are plenty of contents where ***here*** and ***there*** are completely interchangeable. Suppose you and your partner are the same distance away from your dining table: *"Where are my car keys?", **Here / There** on the table.*

Comment: I've never heard of anyone ever saying "I got safe at work." Does that mean they obtained a safe at work? Does it mean they got saved at work? Does it mean that they were dangerous but somehow obtained safety at work? Where did you learn that construction?

Comment: Is anyone else bothered by 4 buts, an and, and a because, all in the same run on sentence? Nvm

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the meaning of your statement was "I wanted to know if you got to work safe."

If so, I'm a native speaker and I can confirm "I got there safe" is correct.

If your boyfriend is not currently at work, then "here" is of course not appropriate and "there" must be used.

Let's expand "there" to it's definition, "that place." "That" can refer to an object that is relatively distant from the speaker - which would seem to suggest that your boyfriend couldn't call somewhere he is currently "that place." However, "that" can also refer to an object understood from the conversation/situation. For example, "I got into bed. Immediately after that I fell asleep." Even though those events are proximate in time and space, "that" is still used to refer to the event that of the prior sentence.

Answer (score -1):

With both participants as native speakers i would say as long as the meaning is understood just roll with it. Unfamiliar idioms can become familiar and in fact charming over time. I will say that use of "safe" when i prefer "safely" is quite jarring to me, but many English speakers might find it to sound natural.